# Why can the net.msmq binding in WCF not be used in this way?

Tags: wcf, msmq

I am trying to host a WCF service over net.msmq.

The following code gives me "*The communication object, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.*" Why is this? It works for net.tcp and http, so I **assumed** it should work for msmq, too.

I have already created a private message queue named "HelloIndigo".

```
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloIndigoService),
                   new Uri("net.msmq://localhost/private/HelloIndigo")))
{
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IHelloIndigoService),
                            new NetMsmqBinding(), "HelloIndigoService");
    host.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to terminiate the service host.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling tracing, this should give you some exception info.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx